# spatiotemporal prediction using support vector regression

Tags: machine-learning, regression, prediction, geospatial, svr

i am using a geographic dataset and i intend to use SVR as machine learning method for predicting spatiotemporal patterns from this dataset.

My question is does SVR canensure spatiotemporal prediction from geographic datasets?

Comment: Yes, it can, but Gaussian process regression is a better fit for the spatiotemporal case because it affords greater flexibility and, like SVR, it also uses kernels; search for "spatiotemporal gaussian process regression". Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thank you .. i will do as told but do you know from where to start with spatiotemporal prediction : tools choice, methodologies ..

Comment: Try [GPflow](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow) or [pyro](http://docs.pyro.ai/en/dev/contrib.gp.html).